# Table For Setting

Tags: database, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, settings

I am developing an application, in this application a user can configure some settings. It is good to have table like this for storing settings? Just a 1 row that can be updated.

```
 School_Name    School_Address    School_Principal     OtherSettings
 someSchool     someAddress       somePrincipal        someValue
```

OR have this kind of table:

```
 Setting_ID    Setting_Description    Setting_Value
 1             School Name            someSchool
 2             School Address         someAdress
 3             School Principal       somePrincipal
 .....
```

Comment: Name/value pairs (NVPs) tend to suffer from data type and validation issues as they grow. You might want to allow any 80 character string for a school name, but what about a ZIP code, telephone number, email address, marital (or martial) status, gender, ...? Are values required or optional for specific names? It just keeps getting uglier.

Comment: Name/value pairs (NVPs) is the second one?

Comment: Yes, NVPs have a name (`Setting_Description`) and value (`Setting_Value`) arranged in pairs as in your second example. Aside: Does you application allow more than one user? If so, are you planning to handle separate configurations for each user, e.g. by adding a `UserId` column?

Comment: Yes my application have a Administrative User that can create some UserAccounts to be able to LogIn.

Answer (score 0):

This will greatly depend on if you will allow a user interface designer that can generate new columns/values on the fly, or if this will be only at design time.

If you were to design a system where the user can add new columns/values as they wish, then the key/value pair store would be the route to go.

If you will only change the table structure based on design time decisitions, I would go with the fixed approach.

You need to also take into account the the key/value pair design will be quite difficult once it gets to dynamic report designing, and performance will be something to take into account.